# Python Sorting Script by Rank

Tags: python, sorting

I am new to python so apologies for the general nature of this question. I have done a fair amount of research in how to tackle this problem conceptually and would appreciate some advice in what methods to use to move forward.

I am trying to create a loop that will take ~80 students from a csv, each of whom has ranked 8 different professors by choice and in turn sort them into classes by their top choices:

```
Student 1 = {profA, profC, profH, profD, profE, profB, profG, profF}

Student 2 = {profB, profD, profH, profE, profA, profC, profG, profF}

Student 3 = {profC, profC, profH, profD, profE, profB, profG, profF}

..... to Student 80
```

and in turn create a list:

```
ProfA: (Student 1, Student 7, ...)
ProfB: (Student 2, Student 23, ...)
ProfC: (Student 3, Student 8, ...)
```

In the end it will need to optimize the rosters so that students can be put into their second and third choices as each professor can only have 10 students. Along with this, is there anyway to ensure a distribution of students getting their top 3 choices through this method?

Once again sorry for the general nature of this question, but any guidance methodology would be helpful.

Comment: Your syntax is not valid Python. `{}` indicates dictionaries or sets, but your question suggests that those are lists, which should be `[]`.

Comment: I am confused by the last optimization. Are you saying that if a professor doesn't have 10 first choices, add second/third choices until the professor reaches 10 choices? Does a professors list of first choices cut off at 10 even if there are more? Does there need to be a delineation between first, second, or third choice students in the list?

Comment: @Malonge That is correct.

Comment: Sorry hit enter too soon, each professor has to have at least 10 students, and if they aren't listed as first then they will need to be filled by another student who listed them as either second or third.

Comment: Are only the top three considered or does it keep going until ten choices are found?

Comment: @Malonge It keeps going until ten choices are found. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the real format of your input is:

```
Student_1, profA, profC ...
Student_2, profB, profD
.
.
.
Student_80,...,...
```

Then you can simply parse the data into a dictionary.

```
masterDict = {}
profVotes = {}    
f = open('your_csv_file.csv')
for line in f:
    L1 = line.split(',')
    # {Student: [first choice, second choice, third choice...]}
    masterDict[L1[0]] = [L1[1], L1[2], L1[3], L1[4], L1[5], L1[6], L1[7], L1[8]]

    # Make a key for each professor in the final dictionary.
    # Initialize list of students who voted for that professor.
    for i in range(1,9):
        if L1[i] not in profVotes.keys():
            profVotes[L1[i]] = []

# Fill list in order of vote.
for j in range(8):
    for student in masterDict.keys():
        profVotes[masterDict[student][j]].append(student)

# Cap the list at 10
for prof in profVotes.keys():
    profVotes[prof] = profVotes[prof][:9]
```

I didn't really have a change to debug this so theres likely errors, however the comments provide the general idea.

Comment: One bug I changed = student to .append(student). That should do the trick.